# How to install bootstrap to angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to install bootstrap to angular

This is the code I am entering:
npm install bootstrap jquery --save

I then get this back:

up to date, audited 1013 packages in 3s

92 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

But when I try running ng serve I'm getting an error message:

An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ Laptop\D1\node_modules\bootstap'
See "C:\Users\laptop\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-uVEA31\angular-errors.log" for further details.

I'm not sure what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Run this npm command instead `npm i angular-bootstrap`

Comment: Just tried this and the same errors happened

Comment: Check that the path where your `npm` is installed globally on your machine is correct, given the error you're experiencing I'd reinstall `node`.

Answer (score 0):

This is among the ones used the most:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command

```
$ npm install bootstrap
```

The Bootstrap assets will be installed in the node_modules/bootstrap folder.
You can include Bootstrap files from node_modules/bootstrap using the index.html file.

Open the src/index.html file and add the following tags:

A `<link>` tag for adding the bootstrap.css file in the `<head>` section.
A `<script>` tag for adding the bootstrap.js file before the `</body>` tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>  
<title>Angular Bootstrap</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
</head>
<body>  
<app-root></app-root>  
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo somewhere "C:\Users\ Laptop\D1\node_modules\**bootstap**". It shoud be "bootstrap"